# Show tags and an associative id

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, php-5.3

I have a problem...I want to show with an echo the tag_name an the id:
My array:

```
 Array
 (
 [id] => 15
 [title] => This is the first article
 [content] => 

This is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the    first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first articleThis is the first article

[date] => 2014-05-11 12:05:00
[views] => 0
[smallimage] => Hydrangeas-11.jpg
[largeimage] => Hydrangeas-11.jpg
[tags] => first tag,last tag,second tag
[id_tag] => 15,16,17
)
```

I tried, but when I link I get in brower: localhost/blogCI/tag/15,16,17 but I need to show localhost/blogCI/tag/15 or localhost/blogCI/tag/16
My code:

```
<div class="news-content-title">
            <? echo $main_info['title'];?>
        </div>
        <div class="news-content-content">
            <? echo $main_info['content'];?>
        </div>


        <?php foreach($main_info as $n):?>
                        <?php $tags = explode(",", $n['tags']); ?>
                        <?php $id_tag = explode(",", $n['id_tag']); ?>

        <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php for ($i=0;$i<count($id_tag);$i++): ?>

                    <a href="<?php echo base_url('tag/'.$main_info['id_tag'])?>"><?php echo $main_info['tags'] ?></a>

        <?php endfor; ?>
```

Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not particularly sure about the syntax as I  haven't worked with codeigniter but you could try this:

```
<?php
      $tags['tags'] = explode(",",$main_info['tags']);
      $tags['id_tag'] = explode(",",$main_info['id_tag']);

         foreach($tags['tags'] as $k=>$v): ?>
           <a href="<?php echo base_url('tag/'.$tags['id_tag'][$k])?>"><?php echo $v ?></a>
         <?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: @user3613935 Could you `print_r($tags);` before the `foreach`?

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => 1
)

Array
(
    [0] => T
)

Array
(
    [0] => <
)

Array
(
    [0] => 2
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
)

Array
(
    [0] => H
)

Array
(
    [0] => H
)

Array
(
    [0] => f
)

Array
(
    [0] => 1
)

Comment: @user3613935 Oops, I assumed it to be a single array, try the edited code.

Comment: Now in the view print : 1 A < 2 8 J J i 1

Comment: it's get the first later from all component of array

Comment: @user3613935 This is getting weirder, could you paste the above code  after the `</div>` and try?